# Why is Bash ignoring the second half of the script?

Tags: bash, terminal, ftp, heredoc

Screenshot of code executing

[image]

I'm wondering why my code is not working. It connects via SFTP, however no files are transferred, no feedback is given on the second half of code, and no errors are presented.

```
#!/bin/bash
export username=xxx
export password=xxx
export url=xxx
export port=2222
export path=//wp-content/uploads/2021/01/TEST
wget ftp://$username:$password@$url:$port/* -P $path

lcd volume1/IT_Services/TEST
cd volume1/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/TEST
ls -1 volume1/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/TEST
binary
put TEST.txt
bye
```

Output:

```
Resolving xxx... 00.000.00.00
Connecting to xxx|00.000.00.00|:2222... connected.
```

Comment: `lcd` is not a shell command, it's a ftp command. You can't call ftp commands from a shell script directly.

Comment: Everything after `wget` looks like it's intended to be a here-doc input to `ftp`.

Comment: `wget` is still running, waiting for the input that you put in the shell script.

Comment: @chepner `wget` is not an interactive command.

Comment: @Barmar I'm wondering about the lack of any error like "lcd: command not found" if the script were actually progressing past `wget`. (Maybe there is, and the OP isn't reporting it.)

Comment: FYI: There's no need to export the variables. And you should make a habit of quoting variables in case they contain special characters.

Comment: Run the script with `bash -x` to see a transcript of the commands as they're executing.

Comment: @chepner I didn't get that error unfortunately.

Comment: @choroba what do you suggest I change?

Comment: @Barmar I tried that and did not get useful feedback. How would I change to a here-doc input to ftp?

Comment: `ftp "$username@$url" <<bye`